# Kivy how to rotate a picture

Tags: python, kivy

i'm trying to rotate some pictures i have to show on the screen, these picture are inside a stacklayout, and i need to show them as Portrait instead of landscape,i'm using the Image Widget
Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The previous 2 answer of toto_tico is a way to do, but i would rather create a new widget for it, and use it:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<RotatedImage>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: root.angle
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: root.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
''')

class RotatedImage(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty()
```

Then, use this widget as other Image widget, you just have a "angle" property you can play with.

Note: the collision detection is not handled on the image, except in the scatter example. Scatter can be expensive just for rotate something, but at least the collision works.

Comment: Thanks i will try it later, it seem the best solution, thanks for your help, i'm quite new to kivy i still miss something on how the framework works :)

Comment: It's important always to be object oriented. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the [Scatter](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html) is meant to be use for this. But I guess is a more intuitive solution. The Scatter includes a rotation (and also a scale) property.

Basically, I embedded the Image inside a Scatter and use the rotation property to rotate 90 degrees.

Why do I say the [Scatter](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scatter.html) is not meant for this task. Basically because it allows gestures over it. You can basically translate, rotate or scale with your fingers (or using the [multi-touch mouse emulation](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.providers.mouse.html)). That is why in the next example I am setting the `do_scale`, `do_rotation` and `do_translation` to false. I am clarifying this before you get confuse with the `do_rotation: false`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Example>:
    Image:
        source: 'kivy.png'
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 64,64
    Scatter:
        pos: 0,0
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 64,64
        do_rotation: False
        do_scale: False
        do_translation: False
        rotation: 90
        Image:
            source: 'kivy.png'
            size_hint: None,None
            size: 64,64

""")

class Example(App, StackLayout):
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think they are two ways of doing this. I'll post two answers and let others decide what is the right approach. I personally prefer this method because I think it's computational lighter. However, it is not that intuitive

This method uses a RelativeLayout and two context instructions (Rotate and Translate).

1 - You need to embed the Image inside the [RelativeLayout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html). Why? Because the way Rotate works is similar to putting a nail in the (0,0) coordinate, i.e. bottom-left corner. The [RelativeLayout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html) sets the 0,0 to the position of the Widget.

2- You will need to use the [canvas](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/graphics.html)

3- As I said before, the Rotate instruction is equivalent to put a nail in the (0,0) coordinate. Think about a piece of paper. If you put a nail in the corner the rotation is going to end on the left. So, before the rotation, you need to [Translate](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Translate) the piece of paper to your right.

4- Now you can [Rotate](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Rotate) the RelativeLayout and It will end in the position you are expecting.

There is another advantage of using a RelativeLayout. It already includes two important instructions  ([PushMatrix](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.context_instructions.PushMatrix) and [PopMatrix](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.context_instructions.PopMatrix)) that you must understand if you are extensively working with rotating, scaling or translating.

Here is an example code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Example>:
    Image:
        source: 'kivy.png'
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 64,64
    RelativeLayout
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 64,64
        canvas.before:
            Translate:
                x: 64
            Rotate:
                angle: 90
                axis: 0,0,1
        Image:
            source: 'kivy.png'
            size_hint: None,None
            size: 64,64
""")

class Example(App, StackLayout):
    def build(self):
        return self

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().run()
```