# Kivy Behaviors Import error from kivy.uix.behaviors

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to run code from the [first answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461336/rotating-an-object-on-a-touch-event-in-kivy).

I am getting the following error trying to import behaviors from the kivy garden:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "fromSO.py", line 3, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.geartick import GearTick
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/garden.py", line 81, in load_module
     return self._load_module(fullname, moddir)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/garden.py", line 85, in _load_module
     ('', '', imp.PKG_DIRECTORY))
   File "/home/username/.kivy/garden/garden.geartick/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from geartick import GearTick
   File "/home/username/.kivy/garden/garden.geartick/geartick.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
 ImportError: No module named behaviors
```

I have done:

```
$ pip install kivy-garden
$ garden install geartick
$ cd
$ cd kivy
$ git pull kivy
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace -f
$ make
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Comment: Which version of Kivy do you use? Behaviours are new in 1.8.0 as you can see in documentation: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you remove all previous installations of kivy...

```
pip uninstall kivy
sudo apt-get remove python-kivy
```

To be sure kivy is uninstalled run the following command

```
python -c "import kivy"
```

If you get a line like::

```
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.x.x...
```

Then you still have kivy installed somewhere and need to figure out where it is installed and uninstall it.

Next Install latest kivy(1.8) from github

```
cd /Where/You/Want/Kivy
git clone http://github.com/kivy/kivy
make
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/kivy/clone
```

To check if kivy is setup and working ::

```
python -c "import kivy"
```

Should give you

```
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.0-dev
```

Or wait a few days 1.8 is due to be released in a couple of days

Comment: Hmm, I ran all of that and it looked successful, but now the error I get is:     `from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named kivy.app` and the parts of kivy that used to work are broken.

Comment: Oh, I missed the path export.  That took care of it.  Thanks.

Comment: Do people usually make the export path permanent?  Or how do you deal with that?  I rebooted and it doesn't work anymore.  I understand it's not hard to make that permanent, but wonder if that's the normal practice.

Comment: for development purposes it's easier to just add it to your PYTHONPATH rather than install it this way you can different version of kivy available and just set the appropriate path (or you could use virtualenv). If you want to set the path permanently just add it to your ~/.bashrc