# Kivy: user touch and drag for cropping function

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm attempting to crop an image. The basic idea is that the user will drag his mouse over the image to crop it. To that end, when you click "Crop", the user can select a lower left point, then drag the rectangle up to the top right. The rectangle should shade the outside area not selected.

I've been researching Drag behavior and simpler methods such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461336/rotating-an-object-on-a-touch-event-in-kivy) (attempted below), but with little results. As a bonus, is it possible to limit the area the user can touch and drag?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Point
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""

<MyScreenManager>:
    ThirdScreen:
        id: third_screen

<ThirdScreen>:
    name: '_third_screen_'
    id: third_screen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: third_screen_boxlayout

        Label:
            id: main_title
            text: "Title"
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
        BoxLayout:
            id: image_box_layout
            Image:
                id: main_image
                source: "C:/Users/OneDrive/0. T2/6. Kivy/4/claymore.jpg"
        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)
            Button:
                id: accept_button
                text: "Okay"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.image_accepted_by_user(root.image_address)
            Button:
                id: crop_button
                text: "Crop"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.enable_cropping()
            Button:
                id: cancel_button
                text: "Cancel"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1) 
                on_press: root.manager.current = '_first_screen_'
""")

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    def enable_cropping(self):
        print("\nThirdScreen:")
        print(self.ids.main_image.pos)
        print(self.ids.main_image.size)
        print("\tAbsolute size=", self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size)
        print("\tAbsolute pos_x=", self.ids.main_image.center_x - self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size[0] / 2.)
        print("\tAbsolute pos_y=", self.ids.main_image.center_y - self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size[1] / 2.)

        self.ids.image_box_layout.add_widget(DrawInput(size_hint=(0.00000000000001, 0.00000000000001)))

class DrawInput(Widget):
    # for cropping
    draw = True
    rect_box = ObjectProperty(None)
    t_x = NumericProperty(0.0)
    t_y = NumericProperty(0.0)
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = 0.0

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.draw:
            color = (1, 1, 1, 0.4) # red, 40% shaded
            win = self.get_parent_window()
            touch.ud['group'] = str(touch.uid)

            with self.canvas:
                # variable drag
                Color(*color, mode='hsv')
                self.x1 = touch.x
                self.y1 = touch.y
                self.t_x = touch.x
                self.t_y = touch.y

                self.rect_box = [Rectangle(pos=(0, self.y1),
                                           size=(win.width, -self.y1),
                                           group=touch.ud['group']),
                                  Rectangle(pos=(0, self.y1),
                                            size=(self.x1, win.height),
                                            group=touch.ud['group']),
                                  Point(points=(self.x1, self.y1),
                                        source='particle.png',
                                        group=touch.ud['group']),

                                  Rectangle(pos=(self.t_x, self.y1),
                                            size=(win.width - self.t_x, win.height - self.y1),
                                            group=touch.ud['group']),
                                  Rectangle(pos=(self.t_x, self.t_y),
                                            size=(self.x1 - self.t_x, win.height - touch.y),
                                            group=touch.ud['group']),
                                  Point(points=(self.t_x, self.t_y),
                                        source='particle.png',
                                        group=touch.ud['group'])]

                touch.grab(self)
                print(self.x1, self.y1)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            # not working
            self.t_x = touch.x
            self.t_y = touch.y
            print(self.t_x, self.t_y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            # only 1 draw
            self.draw = False
            # final position
            self.x2 = touch.x
            self.y2 = touch.y

            print(self.x2, self.y2)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to remove the DrawInput class and integrate the on_touch_down, on_touch_move and on_touch_up into the Screen. NumericProperty() and ObjectProperty() allow the rectangle, wrote as a widget canvas into the kv file, to be manipulated.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.graphics import Point
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""

<MyScreenManager>:
    ThirdScreen:
        id: third_screen

<ThirdScreen>:
    name: '_third_screen_'
    id: third_screen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        id: third_screen_boxlayout
        Label:
            id: main_title
            text: "Title"
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
        BoxLayout:
            id: image_box_layout
            Image:
                id: main_image
                source: "C:/Users/Mark/OneDrive/0. T2/6. Kivy/4/claymore.jpg"
            Widget:
                id: image_canvas
                size_hint: (0.0000001, 0.0000001)
                canvas:
                    Rectangle:
                        id: root.rect_box
                        pos: (root.x1, root.y1)
                        size: (root.t_x, root.t_y)
        BoxLayout:
            id: button_boxlayout
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding: 10
            size_hint: (1, 0.15)
            Button:
                id: accept_button
                text: "Okay"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.image_accepted_by_user(root.image_address)
            Button:
                id: crop_button
                text: "Crop"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1)
                on_press: root.enable_cropping()
            Button:
                id: cancel_button
                text: "Cancel"
                size_hint: (0.33, 1) 
                on_press: root.manager.current = '_first_screen_'
""")

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ThirdScreen(Screen):
    rect_box = ObjectProperty(None)
    t_x = NumericProperty(0.0)
    t_y = NumericProperty(0.0)
    x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = NumericProperty(0.0)

    def enable_cropping(self):
        print("\nThirdScreen:")
        print(self.ids.main_image.pos)
        print(self.ids.main_image.size)
        print("\tAbsolute size=", self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size)
        print("\tAbsolute pos_x=", self.ids.main_image.center_x - self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size[0] / 2.)
        print("\tAbsolute pos_y=", self.ids.main_image.center_y - self.ids.main_image.norm_image_size[1] / 2.)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.x1 = touch.x
        self.y1 = touch.y
        self.t_x = touch.x
        self.t_y = touch.y

        touch.grab(self)
        print(self.x1, self.y1)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            # not working
            self.t_x = touch.x
            self.t_y = touch.y

            print(self.t_x, self.t_y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            # final position
            self.x2 = touch.x
            self.y2 = touch.y

            print(self.x2, self.y2)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```